# How do I fix manifest-update lifecycle error of android-maven-plugin in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, android-maven-plugin

When I import an Android Maven project into my Eclipse workspace I am seeing this error in pom.xml:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:
>   com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.1:manifest-update
>   (execution: update-manifest, phase: process-resources)

How do I fix it? I am using android-maven-plugin 3.6.1, m2eclipse 1.4, m2e-android 0.4.2 and Eclipse Kepler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with the [Android M2E Connector](http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/):

https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/78

There is a workaround, you can disable this error message by using the quick fix provided by the m2e plugin:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by putting all plugins inside a `<pluginManagement>` tag:

```
<build>
 <pluginManagement>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
       ...
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
 </pluginManagement>
</build>
```